# Attempting to create relationship between 10,000 songs and their artist

Tags: neo4j

I am using neo4j to create a graphDB of some song data.

I have a CSV file containing all the data, and I currently have `Song` nodes in my graph which represent each song in the dataset. I have played around and attempted a few different ways of creating `Artist` nodes, but I either end up with the same song have multiple relationship to separate `Artist` nodes of the same name, or just run into errors.

I am new to neo4j, so I don't know all the tricks and correct syntax for everything.

Currently this is what I have:

`Song` nodes for each song which contain: title, artistName, and tempo

`Artist` nodes which contain: artistName, artistHotness, and a familiarity score (to be used later for recommending new music)

`Tempo` nodes of different ranges (ex: 1-80, 81-110, etc).

I have successfully formed relationships between `Song` nodes and `Tempo` nodes, but am unsure how to form relationships between `Song` nodes and `Artist` nodes which don't form duplicates or introduce a new `Artist` node every time the artist has a song in the database (ex: there are 10k songs in the list, and attempting to import row.artistName results in 10k `Artist` nodes, even though there should be less artists than songs, since I know that some artists have multiple songs in the list).

Any help forming the relationships between `Song` nodes and `Artist` nodes is appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you are only using `MATCH` and `CREATE`. Look at also using [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/)

Comment: It would help if you showed the command you are using.

Comment: If a popular song is recorded by multiple artists, do you have multiple `Song` nodes with the same `title` but different `artistName` values? And what if the same artist re-records the same song, perhaps even at different tempos -- do you again have multiple `Song` nodes for that song for that single artist (and with the possibility that some nodes will appear to be duplicates, but for different recordings)? You really need to carefully rethink your data model.